# MySQL 5.6 users index instead of range type select on a big table and simple query

Tags: mysql, index, performance, join, mysql-5.6, query-performance

We have recently migrated from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 (`5.6.44-86.0-log Percona Server` to be precise) and we have a huge problem. Seemingly simple queries run for minutes instead of milliseconds on a table with 300+ million records.

This is the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` double(16,6) NOT NULL,
  `score` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `feed_id_date` (`feed_id`,`date`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Yes, `date` is `double` because we need microsecond precision. One solution we haven't yet explored is to turn it into `bigint`.

Here is a typical query that fails:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT a.id FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id IN (6826,6827) AND a.date < 1564469723.424363 ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 20;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | feed_id_date,date | feed_id_date | 12      | NULL | 339355570 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the number of rows. It's practically a full table scan. This query runs for 3-5 minutes, which is unacceptable for an OLTP load. Now see the following two queries where we select the two `feed_id` in question one by one:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT a.id FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id IN (6826) AND a.date < 1564469723.424363 ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 20;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | feed_id_date,date | feed_id_date | 12      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT a.id FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id IN (6827) AND a.date < 1564469723.424363 ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 20;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | feed_id_date,date | feed_id_date | 12      | NULL |  473 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And indeed this is the correct number of rows for each `feed_id`:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id=6826;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id=6827;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      474 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is very puzzling to me. We have all kinds of combinations in the `IN` clause. Some users have 1000+ `feed_id` records that run OK, but in some situations two records in the `IN` clause are enough to cause a full table scan.

In the `EXPLAIN` it's visible that the problem only arises when the `type` is `index`, and not `range`. On our old MySQL 5.5 instance `EXPLAIN` on the same queries and the same dataset always shows `range` type and we never had such issue.

Could this be config related? Here's my `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]

skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

transaction-isolation           = READ-COMMITTED

max_connections                 = 5000
max_user_connections            = 4500
back_log                        = 2048
max_allowed_packet              = 128M

sort_buffer_size                = 256K
read_buffer_size                = 128K
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 256K

join_buffer_size                = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 8M
query_cache_limit               = 1M
query_cache_size                = 0
query_cache_type                = 0
key_buffer                      = 10M
thread_stack                    = 256K
thread_cache_size               = 100
tmp_table_size                  = 256M
max_heap_table_size             = 1G
query_cache_min_res_unit        = 1K

character-set-client-handshake  = FALSE
character-set-server            = utf8mb4
collation-server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 46G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 32
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_io_capacity              = 50000
```

The VM has 64GB RAM and 100k+ iops storage, but this is surely not hardware related.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the `feed_id` field to the `ORDER BY` clause like that:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT a.id FROM articles a WHERE a.feed_id IN (6826,6827) AND a.date < 1564469723.424363 ORDER BY a.date DESC, a.feed_id DESC LIMIT 20;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | feed_id_date,date | feed_id_date | 12      | NULL |  474 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not sure if this is the correct way, looks a bit hacky to me, especially since this is not needed in `5.5`, so if anyone else has a better solution, let me know.

Comment: When it works, in a reasonable length of time, it is WORTH the additional ORDER BY to help the Optimizer get it completed quicker.

Comment: In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html  we find the following Optimizer enhancements.  These query optimizer improvements were implemented:

The optimizer now more efficiently handles queries (and subqueries) of the following form:

SELECT ... FROM single_table ... ORDER BY non_index_column [DESC] LIMIT [M,]N;
That type of query is common in web applications that display only a few rows from a larger result set. For example:

Comment: The change was made between 5.5 and 5.6 where MySQL is depending on us to provide the ORDER BY.  Similar doc exists in 5.7 changes with more explanation if you searh for ORDER BY.

Comment: Thanks. It mentions `non_index_column`. I'm not sure it's the same case though.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce the 'amount of work per second'
```

To conserve about 90% of CPU cycles used for this function, per

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lru_scan_depth

when you have innodb_buffer_pool_instances=32.

Comment: @Jacket This is a dynamic Global Variable.  Using root, you could SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=100;

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and see if it changes anything, though it's not related to the issue.

Comment: Not related but will save 90% of CPU cycles used every second for this function.  May see your CPU% reduced in TOP or HTOP.

Comment: @Jacket For additional suggestions and free Utility Scripts, see my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: I don't think it had any visible effect on my graphs and I left it for almost a day. Maybe it's more prominent on less loaded servers where bigger part of the load comes from static operations and not clients. Also we had a very curious incident yesterday. Without any visible cpu or io bottleneck we had big contention and QPS dropped from 20k to 2k. This happened twice for about 5 minutes and almost led to an outage. Queries were regular and no locks were observed. So I returned `innodb_lru_scan_depth` to the default value of `1024` and the issue didn't appear anymore.

Comment: Would like to see a TOP at 1024, set scan depth to 100 and get another TOP after 2 minutes at 100, please.  Per the refman, WORKLOAD is instances*value of scan_depth,  When 32 instances x 1024=32768 vs 32 x 100=3200 WORKLOAD.  Do you monitor innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty?  Can be checked anytime with SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%pages_dirty%';

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile and we have free Utility Scripts available and offer additional performance tuning suggestions, hoping to hear from you. Thanks

Comment: @Jacket One more GV to consider.  What is result of SELECT @@innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay?  This is number of microseconds to delay when busy. 150000=15 seconds  My usual recommendation is 20000 for 2 seconds max delay.